# How can i fix this? Splice is not a function Vuex

Tags: vuex, splice, mutation

I want to remove an Id in an array of id in events of the user in vuex. Here is the code my mutation

```
REMOVE_USER_EVENT (state, payload) {
    state.user.events.splice(payload, 1)
  }
```

it says splice is not a function. `state.user.events` are arrays of event Ids of the user.

this is the user object

```
user:{
events: Array(0)
_id: "5e44d7060572343b58aab"
email: "test@example.com"
firstName: "Jtest test"
lastName: "Test"
address: "Jtest"
phoneNum: "05469874897"
}
```

Comment: If `splice` is not a function then `state.user.events` is almost certainly not an array. Some console logging or a breakpoint should confirm.

Comment: if it says so, certainly `state.user.events` isn't an array at the time you call `.splice()` on it. Please provide more information about how you set its value, initialize it, etc... There is not enough information there

Comment: updated. that is my state.user

Comment: And you never modify its value?

Comment: Are you sure that is how the state looks just before running `state.user.events.splice(payload, 1)`? Console.log just before that

Comment: yes i console log my state.user. that is how it looks

Comment: Try logging `state.user.events` and `state.user.events.splice` instead. Just logging `state.user` isn't that helpful as the object in the console is live and will show the current contents, not the contents at the point it was logged.

Comment: `["5e44b28d472ec3368087999a", __ob__: Observer]
0: "5e44b28d472ec3368087999a"` this is how state.user.events look. i console logged it

Comment: ... and `console.log(state.user.events.splice)`?

Comment: it says undefined. I want to use .splice to remove the eventId inside the state.user.events

Comment: so that the state.user.events would remove the eventId I want to remove. which is from payload

Comment: Something doesn't add up. If it's an array then it should have a `splice` method. Put in a breakpoint and dig in. `splice` should be inherited through the prototype chain. Vue replaces the native Array prototype with its own but `splice` should still be there.

Comment: I dont know why its saying its not a function. when i searched on others its the same but when i used it it says `.splice` is not a function. and state.user.events is an array.

Comment: I tried this one. 
`let events = [state.user.events]

    events.splice(payload.eventId, 1)` no error but it did not mutated

Comment: @PeterParker `import Vue from 'vue'` & try `Vue.set(state.user, 'event', events.splice(payload.eventId, 1));` https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set